# What write in app access for sending data

Tags: support, app, javascript, write-access

Here is my app's code:

[image: app's code]

However, I get this error:

[image: pop-up with the error "applications must have a registered Stack Apps post to write"]

Answer (score 4):

From the [documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/write):

> **Apps must have a registered Stack Apps post to write.**

The next sentence (about links pointing back) is no longer true, but the one after that is right and important too:

> You can add or change your app's registered post from the [Stack Apps App Management page](http://stackapps.com/apps/oauth).

Since this question is tagged [app](/questions/tagged/app), you can use this one as the registered post, even though *officially* you should use another one. For testing purposes, it's fine I guess.