# How to get write_access to comment/answer on Stack Exchange

Tags: support, app, script, stackapps, write-access

I'm trying to integrate the Stack Exchange API into my web app so I can fetch all posts as well as I can post answer or comments on them. I have successfully got `access_token` for **no_expiry** and **private_info** and they are working as well. But when I'm trying to get the `access_token` for **write access**, I'm getting an error as:

> Applications must have a registered Stack Apps post to write

Please let me know if anybody is also facing same issue or know how to get access token for **write_access**.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Apps! I think you need to add a question (e.g. this one) as Registered Post to your app, so essentially you'd have the same problem as [this user](https://stackapps.com/q/8840/34061).